# Can a Shimano XTR M9120 lever works with Shimano Zee 4 piston caliper?

Tags: shimano, compatibility

I have one lever XTR9120 (BL-M9120)and one caliper Shimano Zee 4 piston (BR-M640)

Can I mix together these two to work perfect?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to run the Zee caliper with the XTR-9120 lever.

If your use of the bike is for downhill only (higher sustained heat generation), one brake hose would be preferred over the other, and is detailed below.

The [Shimano compatibility cross over grid](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-460&acid=C-186) may provide some help.

From this chart, the brake hose for the Zee four piston caliper (BR-M640) is a SM-BH90-SBLS. The brake hose for what I would assume you are replacing (BR-M9120?) is slightly different, a SM-BH90-SBM. The only difference between the two is the banjo at the caliper. The BH90 designation represents the brake hose an is common to both brakes, so the hose connection to the lever should be compatible, if not identical.

The banjo on the [SM-BH90-SBLS](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/saint-m820/SM-BH90-SBLS.html) brake hose for the Zee caliper (BR-M640) looks like this:

[image: SM-BH90-SBLS]

Whereas the banjo on the [SM-BH90-SBM](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/service-upgradeparts/xtr-m9100/ISMBH90SBMLL100A.html) brake hose (for an assumed BR-M9120 caliper) looks slightly different:

[image: SM-BH90-SBM]

The difference is the added length of the metal part of the banjo fitting on the SM-BH90-SBLS hose, and the Shimano link to the product states "Long banjo hose, short bolt (for radiation of heat)."  Since the Zee caliper is designed around a downhill setup and heat generation from brakes is a larger concern in that discipline, it makes sense that the longer piece of metal will allow better heat dissipation than the shorter banjo fitting. If you are not running this on a downhill-specific bike, you should be able to run either fitting/hose as the rest of the dimensions are the same.

You should be fine on the brake fluid as it is mineral oil in both cases. You would obviously need to ensure that the rotor and caliper mounting are compatible as well.